# Integrate ASP.NET Identity with QR scan based login

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, qr-code

I am trying to implement a QR code based login mechanism.
Currently, I have a username/password based authentication setup(using ASP.Net Identity). I am also creating a QR-scanner mobile app to interact with the backend.

Currently I am trying the steps from [here](https://galois.com/blog/2011/01/quick-authentication-using-mobile-devices-and-qr-codes/) and [here](http://blog.self.li/post/14864315302/qr-login-howto) for a QR code scan based authentication system.

Are there some solutions available to extend Asp.net Identity better than implementing a custom solution as suggested in the links?
What would be considered a good practice for this?

Appreciate your time for some suggestions.

Comment: Hi I need the same. Any clue?

Comment: @VAAA , I had to leave it midway as client put it on back-burner. I was trying to implement this myself. Qr code contains some random token. On scanning wth mobile app ,we store this with a bearer token in database. Meanwhile, browser keeps polling server with the random key from Qr. On authentication request from mobile, client(browser) gets the bearer token and uses this for further calls to server.